# Formula auto expansion on entire column

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to create a simple spreadsheet to manage expenses. I want it to have column with price of something I bought and next one with updated balance on account - something like this:

[image]

My first idea is to use a simple formula `=E2-D3`...

[image]

...and expand it manually, but I don't want to do it each time I add some new expenses. Is there a way to expand formula to entire collumn?

I've tried with `ARRAYFORMULA`, but following code is giving me an error

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D3:D, E2:E-D3:D, ""))
```

[image]

...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entered in E3:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(D3:D;E2-SUMIF(ROW(D3:D);"<="&ROW(D3:D);D3:D);))`

Comment: Oh, you use comma as a decimal separator in your locale; you will need to use semi-colons as argument separators in this case (answer edited).